# "${fn:escapeXml(parameter)!=null}" is always true

Tags: jstl

I am checking a `parameter!=null` by using `${fn:escapeXml}`,

but it always returns `true` for me.

> e.g `<c:set var="isABC" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.isABC)!=null}"/>`

When the exscape function is removed, it will return `false` if the parameter is null.

> e.g `<c:set var="isABC" value="${param.isABC!=null}"/>`

I would like to know the reason, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple: `escapeXml()` returns an empty string when called with null. And an empty string is not null.

```
public static String escapeXml(String input) {
    if (input == null) return "";
    return Util.escapeXml(input);
}
```